# What is wrong in my attempt to expand the definite integral $\int_0^1\ln(1+x^3)dx$ about $x = 1$ through second degree terms?

Tags: definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

What is the correct way to expand the definite integral $\int_0^1\ln(1+x^3)dx$ about $x = 1$ through second degree terms?

I am getting contradicting answers through different approaches.

**First approach:**

Let $f(x) = \int_x^1\ln(1+x^3)dx = \int_{b(x)}^{a(x)}\ln(1+\zeta^2)d\zeta$ with $g(x, \zeta) = \ln(1+\zeta^3)$, $b(x) = 1$, $a(x) = x$.

By Leibniz's rule,
\begin{align}
f'(x) & = g(x, b(x))\cdot \require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{b'(x)} - g(x, a(x))\cdot a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,\zeta)}d\zeta \\
      & = -g(x, a(x))\cdot a'(x) \\
      & = -\ln(1 + x^3).
\end{align}

Now,
$$ f''(x) = -\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}.$$

Then, using Taylor's expansion around $x = 1$ up to second degree:

$$ \int_x^1\ln(1+x^3)dx \approx  -\ln(2) (x-1)-\frac{3}{4}(x-1)^2 .$$

Since now I have an expansion, I thought I could just substitute $x = 0$ to obtain the expansion of the integral as below

$$\int_{x=0}^1\ln(1+x^3)dx \approx \ln(2)-\frac{3}{4}.$$

**Second approach:**
To verify if the answer above is correct, I tried to just expand from the beginning in the following way.

Let $f(x) = \int_0^1\ln(1+x^3)dx = \int_{b(x)}^{a(x)}\ln(1+\zeta^2)d\zeta$ with $g(x, \zeta) = \ln(1+\zeta^3)$, $b(x) = 1$, $a(x) = 0$.

Again, by Leibniz's rule,
\begin{align}
f'(x) & = g(x, b(x))\cdot \require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{b'(x)} - g(x, a(x))\cdot \require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{a'(x)} + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,\zeta)}d\zeta \\
      & = 0 \\
      & \implies f''(x) = 0..
\end{align}

But then I get a different expansion:

$$ \int_0^1\ln(1+x^3)dx \approx  0.$$

I am more confused because the integral can be evaluated to a constant:

$$ \int_0^1\ln(1+x^3)dx = -3 + \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}} + \ln(4) \approx 0.20009$$

which is different from both results.

Comment: You can try expanding $\ln(1+x^3)$ and integrating term by term (the series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$).

Comment: Okay, I will try that as well. But are my two approaches wrong?

Comment: With “$\approx$” involved, you cannot really say that they are different.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I see...is it legal to just plug in $x = 0$ on the expansion I have from the first approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling victim to your own imprecise notation.  After all, what exactly do you mean by the statement $$f(x) = \int_0^1 \log(1+x^3) \, dx?$$  The RHS is a **constant**.  It uses $x$ as the variable of integration, yet you are using the same variable on the left as if somehow you are expecting the RHS to vary with $x$.  That is why, in your second approach, you get $f'(x) = 0$, because you just found an elaborate way to show that the derivative of a constant is zero.  You don't have this problem in your first approach because you wrote $$f(x) = \int_{\zeta = x}^1 \log(1 + \zeta^3) \, d\zeta.$$  And now the RHS *is* a function of $x$ because $x$ is the lower limit of integration and you have used a different variable of integration $\zeta$.  Well, you didn't really write it exactly this way, instead you wrote the abomination $$f(x) = \int_x^1 \log (1 + x^3) \, dx,$$ but my version is what you *intended*.

Ultimately, were you to use more terms in your series, you would know which approach is correct:  We have $$f(x) \approx -(x-1) \log (2) -\frac{3}{4} (x-1)^2  -\frac{1}{8} (x-1)^3 + \frac{5}{32} (x-1)^4 + O((x-1)^5)$$ where upon evaluating at $x = 0$ yields $$f(0) \approx \log 2 - \frac{15}{32} \approx 0.224397$$ which is reasonably close to the exact value, with even more terms giving better convergence.